# GLib-ERROR : Creating pipes for GWakeup: Too many open files

Tags: c++, file-io, fopen, glib

I am getting this error when running my c++ program under ubuntu 20.04 with clang 9 :

> GLib-ERROR : Creating pipes for GWakeup: Too many open files

I know I have a lot of open files, this is a CGI renderer with a mip-map tiled texture cache, it loads only parts of images in the cache when needed and not the full images, thus keeping files open. There are about 3000 images but it opened only about 1000 before crashing.

What I don't understand is that these texture files are read using stdlib fopen(), not GLib/GTK. So why is the error coming from GLib?

Answer (score 2):

The limit on open files is process- or system-wide. So it doesn't matter whether they are opened by GLib or not (which also uses the same operating system calls to open files, anyway). If you have 1000 files opened at the same time with `fopen()`, consider closing them if you can.